# Run another task after executing one function successfully Using Celery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am new to `celery` module, I want to execute one task after execution of a particular function successfully.

I have done the following changes in my django app:

change `settings.py`:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://rahul:amvarish@127.0.0.1:5672//'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('projectmanagement.tasks',)
```

create `tasks.py`:

```
from celery import task
    @task()
    def add(x, y):
        print (x+y)
        return x + y
```

My `view.py`:

```
class Multiply(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        x = request.GET['x']
        y = request.GET['y']
        try:
            z= x*y
            data = {'success':True,'msg':'x and y multiply','result':z}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")
       except Exception,e:
            print str(e)
            data = {'success':False,'msg':'Error in multiplying x and y'}   
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")
```

Now I want my celery task to get called after the successful execution of my  `multiply` method.

Where should I call my task in my view function, so that my API response will be independent of the celery task execution?

Comment: Hey @piyush-s-wanare I was wondering, was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call your task with the [`.apply_async`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/task.html#Task.apply_async) to make the call asynchronous, which results in the following execution diagram:

```
                                |
                                |
                           normal flow
                                |
                                |            async
                       my_task.apply_async -------> do my task_stuff
                                |            call
                                |
                           flow continues 
                 without waiting on my_task execution
                                |
                               ...
```

Derived from the above-mentioned, in your code you should call your add method as follows:

```
from path.to.your.tasks import add

class Multiply(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        x = request.GET['x']
        y = request.GET['y']
        try:
            z= x*y
            add.apply_async(x, y) # will execute independently 
            data = {'success':True,'msg':'x and y multiply','result':z}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")
        except Exception,e:
             print str(e)
             data = {'success':False,'msg':'Error in multiplying x and y'}   
             return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")
```